# ¿Cómo convertir un arreglo de cadena en número y que el valor cero se convierta a valor null en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, conversión-de-tipos

Tengo el siguiente arreglo:

```
var a = ["1", "2", "0", "4"]
```

... y deseo convertirlo en:

```
[1, 2, null, 4]
```

Hasta ahora he logrado convertir el arreglo de cadena a número con este comando:

```
var g = a.split(",").map(Number);
```

... y me da este resultado:

```
[1, 2, 0, 4]
```

¿Cómo puedo convertir el valor cero en el arreglo a `null`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podes lograrlo utilizando:

- [array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/map) para aplicar una función a cada elemento del arreglo
- Utilizar `+var` para *[cast-ear](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1133814/3791844)* el valor de `var` a número
- Utilizar `var || null` para el caso que `var` sea *[falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Glossary/Falsy)* asignar `null`

Es decir:

```
a.map(i => +i || null);
```

#### Demo:

```js
var a = ["1", "2", "0", "4"];
var g = a.map(i => +i || null);
console.log(g)
```

Answer (score 1):

Si lo que interesa es **modificar** el array, no crear uno nuevo. Puedes hacerlo con `forEach` del siguiente modo.

La clave aquí es que dentro del bucle modificamos cada valor de `a` por su índice al hacer `a[i] = +n || null`, quedando como resultado un sólo array:

```js
var a = ["1", "2", "0", "4"];
a.forEach( (n,i) => a[i] = +n || null);
console.log(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

a partir del resultado, yo haría un map con una condición en la cual vea si el numero es 0, y si es asi le paso null.

```
[1, 2, 0, 4].map(p=>{if(p==0)return null; else return p})
```

Answer (score 0):

1. split es un metodo de String. No deberias llamarlo para dividir un array.
2. Si le pasas Number a map, te devolvera un array en donde cada elemento se le aplica esta funcion. Aqui abandonas el control total de la clase de modificaciones u operaciones que desees realizar.

De acuerdo a las necesidades de tu solucion, una respuesta correcta podria ser.

```js
var a = ["1", "2", "0", "4"]
var g = a.map(value => {
    if(value != 0) {
       return Number(value);
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  });
    
console.log("Antes de mapear valores", a);    
console.log("Despues de mapear valores", g);
```

Recordemos que map puede recibir un callback que, en este caso, es una funcion que es llamada en cada elemento del array. Dicha funcion nos permite tomar el elemento y, de acuerdo a ciertos condicionales, devolver un valor especifico manipulando el mismo. Esto es lo que nos permite verificar si el valor es 0 o no. Si es un numero normal, alli si llamamos Number(value) para retornar el numero. De lo contrario, retornamos null.

Answer (score 0):

Podrias usar findIndex, `findIndex()` devuelve el índice del primer elemento de un array que cumpla con la función de prueba proporcionada. En caso contrario devuelve -1.
una vez encuentras en indice haces el reemplazo

```html
 <script type="application/javascript">
function verificar() {
    var a = ['1', '2', '0', '3'];
    var numbers = a.map(i=>Number(i));
    const index = numbers.findIndex(x => x === 0)
    numbers[index] = null;

    console.log(numbers)
}
</script>


<button onclick="verificar()"> Verificar</button>
```